# How programming related does programming related need to be on StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, superuser, scope

With Super User up and running, I'm seeing some very basic, almost theoretical, type of questions showing up with a general attitude towards pushing the question to Stack Overflow.  I see lots of non-specific and too high level questions closed on Stack Overflow. Are we sending questions to SO from SU that will get closed?

What should be the requirement for closing these types of questions?

Comment: I am slightly confused. High level closed on SO or SU?

Comment: Closing on SO.  ...., x

Comment: Sorry.  Not very good at typing on my iPhone these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a discussion about this on email when I moved a question over that probably shouldn't have been moved (simple Apple scripting).

The general gist was:

- Scripting is Superuser (Scripting != Programming) and programming is StackOverflow
- Client Scripting is SuperUser (Not server scripting or heavy scripting for a sysadmin) otherwise it would be Serverfault
- If it falls into a gray area, err on the side of SuperUser.

Comment: +1 I reached my cap. However I have to agree with this definition. Scripting is not coding, especially around AppleScript. However I know those questions have been asked in the past on both SO and SU.

Comment: See I had the stumbling block to me because Scripting DOES equal Programming in my mind. That's likely because I had a class called "scripting languages" as part of my program for graduating with my degree.

Comment: Understood. But ASP and VBScript is a different kettle of fish. Powershell is also on the border here. PS: You on twitter or some other medium to contact, your profile is a bit sparce.

Comment: Diago: Check my profile on SuperUser

Comment: What? Scripting not programming? So then all the javascript questions should be moved to SU as well?

Comment: JavaScript is not a scripting language. It may once have been, but no longer.

Comment: Have you seen the httpd sever written in a zsh script?
http://zshwiki.org/home/code/scripts/zshttpd there's also zws. So it's hard to draw the line really.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on which voting population is online at the time.